# Ayuda con el tamaño de un video

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Disculpen si quizás es una duda muy básica pero no puedo ajustar un vídeo a un tamaño mayor a 600px con Bootstrap

Dejo el código, si necesitan el `css` también puedo ponerlo.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    
      <head>
    
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="">
    
        <title>Milagro Producciones</title>
    
        <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
        <link href="../vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    
        <!-- Custom fonts for this template -->
        <link href="../vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,800italic,400,300,600,700,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather:400,300,300italic,400italic,700,700italic,900,900italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    
        <!-- Plugin CSS -->
        <link href="../vendor/magnific-popup/magnific-popup.css" rel="stylesheet">
    
        <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
        <link href="../css/creative.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    
      </head>
    
      <body style="background-color: pink;">
    
        <!-- Navigation -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light fixed-top" id="mainNav" style="background-color: #83807F;">
          <div class="container">
            <a class="navbar-brand js-scroll-trigger">LOGO</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
              <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
              <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="../index.html#portfolio"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-left"></i> Volver</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </nav>
    
        <section>
          <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                <h2>TITULO !</h2>
                <hr class="my-4">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-7">
                <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/165810216" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen style="margin-right: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px;"> </iframe>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-5 text-left" style="margin-top: 20px;">
                  <b><i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i> Titulo :</b><p> aqui va el titulo de tu video.</p><hr>
                  <b><i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i> Medio :</b><p> Donde se publico tu video.</p><hr>
                  <b><i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i> Año :</b><p> Año en que se publico tu video.</p><hr>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>
    
    
        <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
        <script src="../vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    
        <!-- Plugin JavaScript -->
        <script src="../vendor/jquery-easing/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../vendor/scrollreveal/scrollreveal.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../vendor/magnific-popup/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>
    
        <!-- Custom scripts for this template -->
        <script src="../js/creative.min.js"></script>
    
      </body>
    
    </html>
```

Comment: No hay problema, si está familiarizado con la grid de Bootstrap, podrás hacer uso de las clases col, usarlas en un etiqueta vídeo sería muy conveniente para tener un diseño adaptable

Answer (score 1):

Yo te recomendaría usar la etiqueta [**`<video>`**](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_video.asp) de HTML5 en lugar de usar  un `<iframe>`.

También no puedes establecer medidas de ancho porcentual directamente en e latributo width o height de una etiqueta, establece esos anchos en los estilos que defines dentro de `style=""`.

```
<video autoplay controls
       style="width: 100%; height: 100%; margin-right: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px;">
  <source src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/165810216" type="video/mp4">
  Tu navegador no soporta el video.
</video>
```

Answer (score 0):

Esto es lo que usé para insertar un video en una pagina y que el video sea responsive

```html
<div style="position: relative; padding-bottom: 56.25%; height: 0; overflow: hidden;">

<iframe style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/188138511?title=0&byline=0&portrait=0" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>

</div>
```

Comment: En realidad iframe solo debería utilizarse en algunas [ocasiones](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/iframe)

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar la etiqueta **video** para asignarle un tamaño y el tipo de controles

```html
<p style="text-align: center;">
<video width="750" height="400" controls="">
<source src="https://dirección/de/tu/video/bienvenida%20360.mp4" type="video/mp4">bienvenida 360.mp4</video>
</p>
```